# adding data to @include throws an error

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

My head is aching as to what is the error in my code.

main.blade.php

```
Html with angular codes here....
@include('modal-template-common', ['link' => route('client.logout')])
```

modal-template-common.blade.php

```
{!! Html::link($link, 'OK', ('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) !!}
```

Now the problems is whenever I try to render it returns an error of

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 273
>
> angular.js:11607 Error: [$compile:tpload]

any enlightenment would greatly help me.

Comment: there is a ')' missing in your `include()` command.

Comment: its just a typo. will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of using `Html` Facade.

But isn't `('class'=>'btn btn-danger')` supposed to be an array ?

So, it should be like this:

```
{!! Html::link($link, 'OK', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) !!}
```

OR

```
{!! Html::link($link, 'OK', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
```

The third argument is an `array`. You can pass any number of `key => value` pairs in this array to assign other related tag's attributes. In your case, the `class` attribute.

For more options, refer [this link](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/186/generating-a-html-link)

Comment: Yes, didn't notice it too. I've finally found my answer. I just used a url method and it works now.

thanks!